# What does the notation "$x_{\cdot n}$" mean?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, notation

I'm currently taking a first course in abstract algebra (group theory), and came across this in a problem:

> Let $n$ be a positive integer. Prove that $(x_{\cdot n}y_{\cdot n})z = x_{\cdot n}(y_{\cdot n}z)$ for all $x,y,z \in \mathbb{Z}$

Now I get that it's proving associativity, but I haven't a clue about what $x_{\cdot n}$ means.. Can anyone educate me?

Comment: How about some context around where you saw it. Context would help quite a bit. My "guess" was going to be that it referred to the product of elements of product groups.

Comment: The notation is not common, so your introductory course *definitely* should provide a definition.

Comment: It's from M.A. Armstrong's Groups and symmetry, the full problem only states extra that $n$ an integer and $x,y,z\in\mathbb{Z}$. I use Dummit and Foote's Abstract algebra instead, so I have very little context to work on. (This is a hand-in).

Comment: Even more fundamental than the notation is to explain what the variables $x,y,z $ mean.  Are these all elements of the same group $G$?

Comment: The full question (quoted above) is all the information I have.

Comment: I believe it's a notation to emphasise the placement of the parenthesis i.e in which order you conduct your operation. E.g $x_{\cdot 3} = ((x\cdot x)\cdot x)$. Perhaps, it's not obvious that any element commutes with itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently:

> $${x_{\cdot n} y} = {xy\bmod n}$$

Answer (score 1):

Probably $x_{\cdot n}$ means $\underbrace{\left(\left(\ldots\left(x\cdot x\right)\ldots\right)\cdot x\right) \cdot x}_{\text{$n$ times}}$ with $x$ multiplied by itself $n$ times.

Comment: It seems like $x^n$ would be much more convenient for that, wouldn't it?

Comment: I'm guessing the point is to stress the group operation and not to suggest $e^{n \log(x)}$.

Comment: In the light of the problem level, I'd even suggest that $x_{\cdot n}=((\ldots (x\cdot x)\ldots)\cdot x)\cdot x$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I absolutely agree and have edited my answer accordingly. This sounds right.